# The name of my frame

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Can you tell me what the name of this frame is?
The handle is Philips.

[image]

Comment: It would be hopeless if it weren't for the rather unusual lugs on the headset.  Perhaps someone will recognize it.

Comment: The rear brake bridge and chainstays look unusual too.  Do you think the seat post is masted up higher than normal?   What is the "handle" that is philips?  - that term doesn't mean anything to me.   Please add some more photos if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, the stays and rear dropouts are kind of odd looking.  The stays almost look like a pair of front forks pressed into this service.  It may well be that the frame is "homemade".

Comment: (And what do you mean by "handle" and "Philips"?)

Comment: The seatstay setup is common old older English bikes as it's easier to fabricate with basic workshop tools. I'd look more for the front lugs, which again look as though they could be hand-made fairly easily. Those holes in the head tube do suggest a badge, though, suggesting some level of manufacturing.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a [Phillips brand English roadster](https://threespeedmania.wordpress.com/tag/1954-philips-3-speed-with-rod-brakes/). The lugs on this example do not match the picture, but the strange looking rear fork and BSA bottom bracket are typical on English 3 speeds.